# Create a csv without the double quotes

Tags: sql, csv

Hello dear community.

I have a csv file that has values with double quotes in them. the csv is used in another script that doesn't like the quotes.

Can you help me re create the csv without quotes around the values.

best regards,

Comment: how are you creating the csv in the first place?

Comment: Quotes around the values or values that contain quotes?

Comment: No the values don't contain any quotes when I output the result in SQL. The csv is created in SQL using Export data options and output the csv in a linux directory.        When the csv is output, it has quotes around the values

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it sounds like it's a setting in your SQL program's export options. You should be able to update that under Tools>Preferences>Database>Utilities>Export>CSV

Link below is a screenshot of the preferences window.

[SQL CSV Export Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5jfK.png)

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your help. I don't have Oracle but tried to access the settings of the GUI I am using and there is no option for csv properties similar to the one you shared. Best,